# Add textbox into iframe and append in a different html

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, textbox

Is it possible to add a textbox into an iframe, and append it into the src of the iframe. So i have created an modal box displaying a button for the user to click "ADD BUTTON"

```
<div id="addFeature" class="openAdd">
        <div>
            <a href="#" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
            <h2>Add...</h2>
            <button class="text" type="button">Text</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

As the user clicks on the button, I need the modal box to close and a text box added. The following iframe is within main.html. As you can see the iframe displays the other html page.

```
<div>
    <iframe class="newIframe" id="newIframe" src="webpage.html" onload="iFrameOn();">
        Your browser does not support Iframes
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Though I need the textbox to be added in webpage.html which is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="iFrameOn();">
    <div id="design">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
addTextBox() {
    var text = "'<div><input type='textbox'/></div>'"
    var textbox = document.createElement('div');
    textbox.innerHTML = text;
    var addText = document.getElementById('div').src = "webpage.html";
    addText.appendChild(textbox);
}
```

Is it possible to do what I'm asking?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, as long as the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) is not violated. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid explaining this in the way you're trying to do this now, would be an endless swamp. Here's some guidelines, how you can achieve this quite easy.

Probably you need to remove the `onload` from `iframe` tag first. Then put these lines to your **main page**:

```
var textForIframe; // Take care that this variable is declared in the global scope
function addText () {
    document.getElementById('newIframe').src = 'webpage.html';
    textForIframe = '<div><input type="text" /></div>'; // or whatever text you need
    return;
}
```

When ever your dialog is ready, call `addText()`.

Then in **webpage.html**, *remove* the `onload` from `body` tag, and add the function below to somewhere after `<script src="index.js"></script>` tag.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var addTextElement = document.getElementById('design'), // or whatever element you want to use in iframe
        textToAdd = parent.textForIframe;
    // depending on what iFrameOn() does, place it here...
    addTextElement.innerHTML = textToAdd;
    iFrameOn(); // ... or it can be placed here as well 
    return;
};
```

These snippets add a new `input type="text"` to `#design` within `iframe`.

Comment: How can I make the text box draggable and resizable?

Comment: Hmm... That's much more complex task, especially with pure JavaScript. I think you should ask a new question about that.

Comment: I've changed my application around, instead of having webpage.html
I have an iframe that is manipulated in the same domain.
Is it still possible to add text boxes in this iframe?

Comment: Ehh... Like I've said in my comment to your question, yes, it's possible. Just post a new question with the relevant code... Btw. if you change your app two months later, that is not supposed to be a reason to unaccept an answer, which worked for the app it was answered for.